# How do i do form validation in the body code which enables/disables a button in my component and at use that button to submit the forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

The buttons are in onboard footer and `<Outlet/>` produces the forms. Was just wondering if there is any way that the buttons in `<OnboardFooter/>` can detect that the form is filled and become enabled and at the same time when pressed, will submit said form?

```
export default function OnboardLayout(){

const [currentPage,setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
const [filled,setFilled] = useState(false);
console.log(currentPage)
console.log(filled)

return (
  <div>
    <OnboardNavBar page={currentPage}/>
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <Outlet />
    </div>
    <OnboardFooter page={currentPage} onPageClick={setCurrentPage} filled={filled} setFilled={setFilled}/>
  </div>
);
```

}

The stack being used here is `Remix-run` and for data validation I am using `Zod`

Answer (score 0):

`Outlet` & `Footer` are sibling components. By lifting the state up to a common parent component, you can share the state changes between the sibling components and pass it down as needed.

```js
const Layout = () => {
    const [formSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(false);

    const handleFormSubmit = () => {
        // Do whatever form submission logic here
        setFormSubmitted(true);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Outlet formSubmitted={formSubmitted} />
            <OnboardFooter onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} />
        </div>
    );
};
const OnboardFooter = ({ handleFormSubmit }) => {
    return <button onClick={handleFormSubmit} disabled={/*add your condition here*/}> Submit </button>;
};

const Outlet = ({ formSubmitted }) => {
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (formSubmitted) {
            // Do the form submission logic here
        }
    };
    return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>{/* Your form fields */}</form>;
};
export default Layout;
```

The form component receives the `formSubmitted` prop from the parent component, and when the form is submitted, it checks if `formSubmitted` is true before performing your form submission logic. You can do something similar using props and handlers to manipulate enabled/disabled the state of the button.

Comment: I actually wanted to detect if the fields are filled correctly before the button is then disabled, at which point the button will then be able to submit the form